# Calling Identity Register.cshtml from controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, controller, asp.net-identity

I have installed Asp.net core Identity and have used it in a previous applications without any real issues.  Login and Register have always used a link from a web page - e.g.:
\<a href="/Identity/Account/Login_Admin?UserType='Admin'" class="text-light">Login\\

However I now need to do some checks in a controller before launching Register.cshtml,  I also want to pass a user id.  I have modified the Register.cshtml.cs adding the id:
`public async Task OnGetAsync(int Id,string returnUrl = null)`
and want to call this from controller.  I have tried:
`return RedirectToAction("/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/Register_Application", new {Id=Applicant.Id });`

`return RedirectToAction("Register","/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/", new {Id=Applicant.Id });`
but both produce a blank screen - the url looks ok but nothing happens.
Any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call razor page with `Redirect`:

```
 TempData["Id"] =Applicant.Id ;
 return Redirect("https://localhost:7090/Identity/Account/Register");//use your port
```

Then in the Register:

```
var Id = TempData["Id"];
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks very much, I've added

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks very much, I've added  var hostname = Request.Host.Value; and added that to the URL so that it would work when deployed.  Thanks also for reminding me of TempData, I've used it a lot in the past but had forgotten how useful it could be.

Comment: Hi @RJPWilliams , you are welcome:)   any update? If my answer help you resolve your issue, could you please accept as answer?
 If not, could you please follow up to let me know? 
Refer to:[How to access an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) Thank you very much.